# Must a subject participate at least twice to be considered in longitudinal analysis?

Tags: panel-data, missing-data

I am currently analyzing longitudinal data that was repeatedly measured (four times) but 1000 participants were lost to follow up after the first survey.

Shall I include or exclude these participants in the longitudinal analysis that have only participated once?

Comment: Related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90677/should-the-outcome-variable-be-measured-at-least-twice-for-a-longitudinal-study) but I am not sure the answers quite respond to what you seek

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of 'participants' engaging is generating a set of data over time, this is called "panel data".  (See Cheng Hsiao's (sp.?) excellent book on this topic, here: [https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Panel-Data-Econometric-Monographs/dp/B000KCI5P0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KCI5P0) )

In general, with panel data, if you have one data point for N of M subjects, they are useless. Panel data analysis is about taking advantage of both the cross-sectional and time-series components of a data set, and one entry sort of violates the linkage of value.